# jQuery: get each element's width and sum them up

Tags: jquery, each, column-width

How can I get each element's width and sum them up?

For instance, here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="block-item" style="width:10px"></div>
<div class="block-item" style="width:50px"></div>
<div class="block-item" style="width:90px"></div>
<div>
```

I can think of looping through each element, but how do I sum the numbers up?

```
$('.block-item').each(function(index) {
    alert($(this).width());
});
```

I want to get the total number of `150 (10 + 50 + 90)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`parseInt(value, radix)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp):

```
var totalWidth = 0;

$('.block-item').each(function(index) {
    totalWidth += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
});
```

Here's an [**example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/BwxCe/).

Comment: Probably want a += for the collector, yes?

Comment: @Alex Thank you, caught that dumb typo myself when I was creating the fiddle.

Comment: 10 is a radix. without it you could get unexpected results when parsing. this way you get base 10 result as opposed to octal.

Comment: If you have the option to use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you could simplify this further by doing `$('.block-item').get().reduce(function(width, el){ return width + $(el).width() }, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

```
var w = GetWidths('.block-item');

function GetWidths(id) {
    var i = 0;

    $(id).each(function (index) {
        i += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
    });

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Clean and elegant usage of variables and functions passed between each other.

Answer (score 0):

for those people who have seen this thread recently:
you can use [jQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) with ease:

```
var y = $('.block-item').map( function() {
    return $(this).width();
}).get()
.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
console.log(y)
```